# How can I specify a dependency between 2 versions of a package?

Tags: packaging, dependencies

In a `debian/control` file, how do I specify a dependency on a package between 2 versions of that package?

For example: python 2.5 or higher but lower than python 2.7.

```
Depends: python ($VERSION_STRING)
```

What would `$VERSION_STRING` be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The operators for version dependencies are:

```
>>  Greater than, but not equal to
>=  Greater than or equal to
=
<=
<<
```

(note `<` and `>`, meaning `<=` and `>=` also work, but they're depricated)

So in order to declare your example, you'd add two dependencies:

```
Depends: python (>= 2.5), python (<< 2.7)
```

For a full description of dependency declarations, see the [Debian Policy Manual, Chapter 7](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html). If you want to take a look at some uses, see [this random example](http://landscape.canonical.com/packages/hardy/Packages).

Answer (score 1):

You can use two clauses to specify the constraints. The first states a dependency on python 2.5 or greater, and the second states a dependency on python earlier than 2.7.

```
Depends: python (>= 2.5), python (<< 2.7)
```